# Extract values from jsonb and merge in to a dataset row

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonb-api

**tableABC**

[image]

I have a PostgreS table with above structure with a JSONB column. I'm using Spring JDBC to retrieve data.
Is there a way to get the row related data in the below structure, using a SQL query.

```
ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|Output Field 1|Output Field 2|
123    |3434   |123    |100           |12            |
34     |56     |656    |1100          |22            |
```

I tried with the method jsonb_to_record(), but got no success.

```
SELECT * FROM
    tableABC,jsonb_to_record(
                columnJsonB->'Output Fields'
        ) AS x(Output Field 1 TEXT, Output Field 2 TEXT)
```

---

**EDIT**-------

As @Bergi mentioned jsonb_to_record works too, with proper quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM
        tableABC,jsonb_to_record(
                    columnJsonB->'Output Fields'
            ) AS x("Output Field 1" TEXT, "Output Field 2" TEXT)
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide simple data as text not image, so it can be easy to help

Comment: `jsonb_to_record` should work, but you need to properly quote your column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is using operator `->` to extract `'Output Fields'` as JSON then apply `->>` to obtain field 1 & 2 as text :

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, 
       columnJsonB->'Output Fields'->>'Output Field 1' as "Output Field 1",
       columnJsonB->'Output Fields'->>'Output Field 2' as "Output Field 2"
from tableABC
```